# How to validate if a column combination already exists in database, rails 6, postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-6

Newbie here!

> ruby 2.7.1, gem --version 3.1.4, Rails 6.0.3.4

I'm getting errors on my query

```
def entry_uniqueness
    if Entry.where("lower(from) = ? AND lower(to) = ?",
                   from.downcase, to.downcase).exists?
      errors.add(:base, 'Identical combination already exists. YUP.')
    end
  end
```

Error:

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "entries" WHERE (lower(from) = 'here' A... ^

Full error

> app/models/entry.rb:35:in `entry_uniqueness' app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:9:in` create' Started POST
> "/entries" for ::1 at 2021-02-13 16:17:47 +0800 Processing by
> EntriesController#create as HTML   Parameters:
> {"authenticity_token"=>"98sjupNso6NW5xUonE/414I7ZvJQETMPBNWS+jcN+PffHaAJ3K0pdQofVPgnrBfflYn2SDXMlB17Q2G/gzideA==",
> "entry"=>{"translation"=>"1", "from"=>"here", "to"=>"there"},
> "commit"=>"Post Translation"}   [1m[36mEntry Exists? (10.2ms)[0m
> [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "entries" WHERE (lower(from) = 'here'
> AND lower(to) = 'there') LIMIT $1[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/models/entry.rb:35:in `entry_uniqueness' Completed 500 Internal
> Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 10.2ms | Allocations: 2140)
>
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax
> error at or near "from" LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "entries" WHERE
> (lower(from) = 'here' A...
> ^ ):    app/models/entry.rb:35:in `entry_uniqueness' app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:9:in` create'

[image: Error message]

---

**What I'm trying to achieve is:**

```
| from  |  to   |
-----------------
| Here  | there |
```

=> validation should prevent the user from adding `heRE  | THERE` but can add `THERE | heRE`

The columns `:from` and `:to` are in the table `entries`.

---

Note: I have tried scopes, they work on uniqueness but they fail on case-insensitivity

```
validates_uniqueness_of :from, scope: :to
```

Also tried

```
validates_uniqueness_of :from, :scope => :to, :case_sensitive => false
```

Also tried @r4cc00n 's implementation but it doesn't work

```
scope :get_entries_by_from_and_to, ->(from, to) { where(arel_table[:from].lower.eq(from)).where(arel_table[:to].lower.eq(to))}
  validates_uniqueness_of :from, if: :entry_uniqueness?

  def entry_uniqueness?
    Entry.get_entries_by_from_and_to('from','to').nil?
  end
```

---

Comment: What is the error with the case sensitive => false scope?

Comment: It is case sensitive, thus failing. E.g entering `Here` `there` is correct uniqueness validation but `HeRe` `TheRe` fails to be restricted hence case-insesitivity failing

Comment: got it, well if you want give it a try to my answer, hope helps you 

Comment: Can you please post the whole error you are receiving on the query from postgres?

Comment: It's a syntax error and the output is only until that. Check new image attached

Comment: Please show the full error message from your log file.

Comment: @spickermann I just added the full error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from` is a [reserved name in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). This makes a lot of sense because read queries usually contain this word (think of `SELECT value FROM table`). Therefore the query that Rails builds from your condition

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "entries" WHERE (lower(from) = 'here' A...
                ^^^^                        ^^^^
```

confused the database. And btw `to` is a reserved name too.

One way to avoid running into this issue like this you should consider renaming the column.

Another easy workaround is to just wrap the column name in double-quotes. Just change your condition to this:

```
Entry.exists?('lower("from") = ? AND lower("to") = ?', from.downcase, to.downcase)
```

Note that I used double-quotes around the column names and single-quotes around the whole condition.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the column naming issues mentioned by @Spickermann you should consider using a [citext (case insentive) type column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/citext.html). It has a number of advantages over your approach:

- You don't have to use a verbose query. `WHERE foo = ?` works regardless of case.
- You can declare a multi-column unique index to ensure uniqueness on the database level - which is case insensitive. This prevents potential [duplicates due to race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

The drawback is that your application will be less portable if you have to switch to another database like MySQL or Oracle which may not be that much of a real concern.

This of course requires you to be able to enable extensions in your Postgres database and you also need to ensure that you are using the same database in testing, dev and production (which is a good idea anyways).

```
class EnableCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension("citext")
  end
end

class ChangeFoosToCitext < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :foos, :bar, :citext
    change_column :foos, :baz, :citext 
    add_index :foos, [:bar, :baz], unique: true
  end
end
```

This will let you use a simple validation with a scope:

```
validates :bar, uniqueness: { scope: :baz }
```

You don't need to use the `case_sentive: false` option which generates an ineffective query.

Comment: You can squish this into a single migration if you want to. I usually use a separate migration for enabling extensions as its easier to debug if it blows up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I think you can fix your query:

You can define a scope within your **Entry** model and then use that scope everywhere, something like below:

```rb
scope :get_entries_by_from_and_to, ->(from, to) { where(arel_table[:from].lower.eq(from)).where(arel_table[:to].lower.eq(to))}
```

Then you can use it: `Entry.get_entries_by_from_and_to('your_from','your_to')` and if that returns `nil` then there is no records in your DB that matches your condition.

With that said if you want to combine that with what you have and with the validation scope you can do it like below:

```rb
def entry_uniqueness?
    Entry.get_entries_by_from_and_to('your_from','your_to').nil?
end
validates_uniqueness_of :from, if: :entry_uniqueness?
```

Be aware that the validates_uniqueness_of is not thread/concurrency safe this means that in a really odd case you can run into some scenarios where you will have not unique data in your DB, to avoid this you should always create a unique index within your DB so the DB will avoid those 'duplicated' scenarios for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried your recommendation but it `doesn't work` on uniqueness either case-insensitivity. Check my edits in the original post about your implementation

Comment: Using Arel to constuct the query will work as it will quote the keys like in @spickermann's answer. However there is no reason why you would have to create a scope which is really just a class method - you can use Arel straight off in the validation. Creating a case insentive unique index on text/varchar columns is also a bit tricky as you have to write the constraint yourself - thus why you would use citext.